# Fiddler Custom rules option is not seen

Tags: fiddler

I am pretty new to fiddler and currently trying to write a custom rule to bypass one of my proxy but according to documentation the custom rule can be navigated via "Rules > Customize Rules...." . Currently i am unable to navigate to this option i don’t see the option in tool , how can i find the custom rule option ?

docs link:
https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Extend-Fiddler/AddRules

[image]

Answer (score 0):

“Fiddler” and “Fiddler Everywhere” are two different tools. Your snapshot shows “Fiddler Everywhere” tool. The document link which you have shared is for “fiddler tool”.

Below link states that Customize Rules are not available in fiddler Everywhere,
https://feedback.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/1458106-custom-rules-engine-in-fiddler-everywhere

If you want to use "Custom Rules", then please install Fiddler tool (not "Fiddler Everywhere") and use custom rule option.